# Why does this snippet with 2 queue runners hang

Tags: tensorflow

I have 2 queues, one for file names, one for holding the contents of those filenames. `tf.train.string_input_producer` adds a QR automatically. I add a QR for enqueuing the second queue. But this code hangs and any advice that will let me figure out what I am missing is appreciated.

```
with tf.Session(graph=tf.Graph(), config=tf.ConfigProto(inter_op_parallelism_threads=4,
                                                        intra_op_parallelism_threads=2)) as sess:

    images, bottlenecks = tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, return_elements=[IMAGE_BATCH, BOTTLENECKS])

    file_name_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(file_names, num_epochs=1, shuffle=False)
    image_queue = tf.FIFOQueue(1024,
                               [tf.float32],
                               [tf.TensorShape([image_size, image_size, 3])])

    reader = tf.WholeFileReader()
    _, contents = reader.read(file_name_queue)

    image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(contents, channels=3)
    image = tf.image.resize_images(image, [image_size, image_size])

    enqueue_op = image_queue.enqueue(image)

    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()

    tf.train.QueueRunner(image_queue, [enqueue_op] * 2)

    sess.run(tf.group(tf.local_variables_initializer(), tf.global_variables_initializer()))

    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)

    while not coord.should_stop():
        image_batch = image_queue.dequeue_many(batch_size).eval()
        print()
        bottleneck_batch = bottlenecks.eval(feed_dict={
            images: np.stack(image_batch)
        })
```

EDIT: After some experiments, I found that the first QR runs but not the second.

Comment: Because the first queue runner is added to tf.GraphKeys.QUEUE_RUNNERS collection, which is what's used to check which queue runners to start -- https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/1708b92bb923e420d746a56baafc7d4ddcd5e05e/tensorflow/python/training/queue_runner_impl.py#L365

Comment: also, your second queue runner is not referenced by anything, so it'll get garbage collected by Python before sess.run

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov Does it (the second QR) not get added to QUEUE_RUNNERS collection implicitly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Queue runners are not added to `tf.GraphKeys.QUEUE_RUNNERS` implicitly. Add any `QueueRunner` you create using `tf.train.add_queue_runner`

This should fix it:

```
qr = tf.train.QueueRunner(image_queue, [enqueue_op] * 2)
tf.train.add_queue_runner(qr)
```

Now calling `tf.train.start_queue_runners` will start this queue runner (`qr`) too.